# ESB module in java

Tags: esb, wso2-esb

i am very new to ESB and i want to implement an ESB module which receives messages to ActiveMQ. Could you suggest me where i should begin. I have installed and got WSO2 and ActiveMQ working together. I am looking for a guide or some links which can help me get a good start at it. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

This provides good set of samples on JMS with ActiveMQ.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/JMS+Usecases

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/JMS+Samples